# Two half columns and 11 in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a proper way of doing `.5 11 .5` in bootstrap? Or I should tweak the style sheet? The `11` column will be an image container.

**UPDATE**
I need the wideness ratio of an 11 that's why i don't want to use `1 10 1`, which will make it narrower by default

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to do a half column in Bootstrap - you need to use 1 - 10 - 1 and control the sizes, padding, margins with CSS. Note also the different classes with regards to sizes (eg :xs, sm, md and lg). You could subdivide each of the columns into its own set of twelve (eg:

```
col-md 1
   col-md-6
   col-md-6

col-md-10

col-md-1
   col-md-6
   col-md-6
```

and then the 10 and one of the 6's from each of the 1's would give you a combined 11 but these would NOT be linked together and would be very funky on smaller screens. Short answer is use 1-10-1 and control the page using CSS

Answer (score 0):

you can try by this method

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-1">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">

            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
<div class="col-xs-10">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">

            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i discussed this method in my post a while ago and whilst it does give the subdivision of the page - does NOT allow a common div to be 11 columns wide - so any image that is housed in the large central column will NOT be included in the side semi columns. This means that the display will not display the central image in 11 columns. There is no direct way of joining the two -6's into the -10 and have them unite. You just cannae do it!